# Convert Greek date with Greek characters to English US

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert a Greek date string to Date en-US. However, I'm getting a FormatException which I'm not sure how to handle:

```
    Dim input = "Τρίτη, 26, 2011" 'Greek characters
    Dim format = "dddd, dd, yyyy"
    Dim dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, New CultureInfo("el-GR")) '<-- Error here
    Dim result = dt.ToString(format, New CultureInfo("es-US"))
    MsgBox(result)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "Tuesday 26, 2011" is not enough data to create a DT var from (no month)

Comment: "Τρίτη, 26 Ιουλίου 2011"

Comment: @Plutonix Correct. Could you please answer the question so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Τρίτη, 26, 2011" translates as "Tuesday, 26, 2011" which is not enough data to create a `DateTime` variable from (there is no month).

You need something like "Τρίτη, 26 Ιουλίου 2011"  (`Tuesday, 26 July 2011`) from wherever you get this from.